# Testing whether the coefficients of one model and another are statistically significantly different

Tags: econometrics, likelihood-ratio

I am currently testing two models which have the exact same specification except for one is when z=0 and when z=1, where z could be something like male and female. Essentially, the effect of X on Y if Z=0 and X on Y if Z=1. 
I want to test whether the coefficients in these models are statistically significantly different from one another.

In my mind I should do some form of likelihood ratio test, but I'm not certain. i was wondering if anybody could confirm my suspicion that I'm wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to incorporate $Z$ into a single model and just test its coefficient within that model?

Comment: I'm not sure. Z isn't actually a gender dummy, it's a dummy for pre-and post financial crisis. So it's the effect of x on y before the crisis and then after. I have two points in time essentially. So if I estimate the effect of X on Y controlling for Z, my Z coefficient beigng significant will tell me there is a difference between the two models?

Comment: @Maarten's answer is correct, but if you have time series data you need to be careful.

Comment: Is every case measured only once, or are they measured once before and once after the crisis?

Comment: @StephenB: Which answer worked best for you? You can accept it to mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like an interaction effect. You estimate the model:

$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2z + \beta_3 x z + \varepsilon $

- $\beta_0$ is the constant when $z=0$
- $\beta_0 + \beta_2$ is the constant when $z=1$
- $\beta_1$ is the effect of $x$ when $z=0$
- $\beta_1 + \beta_3$ is the effect of $x$ when $z=1$

So $\beta_3$ is the difference in effect of $x$ before and after the crisis. If it is 0 there is no difference in effect. This would be your null hypothesis, and the test statistic is (depending on your software) typically reported immediately next to that coefficient.

If $\beta_3$ is positive then the effect of $x$ is larger after the crisis than before. If $\beta_3$ is negative then the effect of $x$ is smaller after the crisis than before.

The model with interactions is almost the same as estimating two separate models. You can see this by looking at the point estimates: these will be exactly the same. The only difference is that you constrain the variance of the error term to be the same before and after the crisis (homoscedasticity). You can easily work around that by asking for robust/Huber-White/sandwich standard errors.

Comment: I'd add to this answer that you can, in fact, use a likelihood ratio to test whether the interaction coefficient is nonzero, since the model with no iteration is nested in the model with interaction.

Comment: Thank you to you all for your help! Unfortunately my reputation is not high enough to vote up your answer but I will be sure to come back when it is!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Maarten that it is an interaction and it should be solved as one model. But, as your variable $z$ is categorical and not continuous, the Maarten's model can be confusing. The model should look like this:

$y = \alpha_z + \beta_z x + \varepsilon $

So, $\alpha_z$ and $\beta_z$ are sex-specific coefficients. This model is called ANCOVA. See example at http://r-eco-evo.blogspot.cz/2011/08/comparing-two-regression-slopes-by.html - R will report the significance of the intercept slope being different for each category (citing the resource). Ugly things will happen if you try to fit $z$ as continuous variable.

Comment: You could call it ANCOVA, but I would just call it linear regression. The sex-specific coefficients are just the result of not excluding the reference category of $z$ in excluding the constant and the main effect of $x$. In my experience, what is considered more confusing greatly depends on what one was told in his/her initial stats courses. I would consider linear regresion the "natural" way of looking at things, but I know others that consider AN(C)OVA to be the more "natural" way of looking at things. I guess we are both right, as long as we remember that they are exactly the same.

Comment: @Maarten what I consider confusing on your answer is not the words, but the formula - your formula works, but it looks like you are treating $z$ as continuous variable instead of categorical one.

Comment: It does not look continuous to me. In my (sub-(sub-))discipline we use this notation all the time for binary explanatory variables. If I were to present this model at a conference in my field, I would not use your formula, as there it would be considered confusing (not wrong, just confusing). I suspect this is a difference in traditions between fields.